# Expand call stored in a variable before passing to function

Tags: r, function

I have a call stored in a variable. If relevant, the call originates from a one-sided formula:

```r
f <- ~ a + b
rhs <- rlang::f_rhs(f)
rhs
#> a + b
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Now, the formula might contain `bquote`-style escaping `.()`, and I want to get all the escaped names.

Looking at `bquote`'s  source code, I created this function:

```r
escapedNames <- function (expr, where = parent.frame()) 
{
    unquote <- function(e) {
        if (is.pairlist(e)) {
            NULL
        } else if (length(e) <= 1L) {
             NULL
        } else if (e[[1L]] == as.name(".")) {
            deparse(e[[2L]])
        } else {
            x <- sapply(e, unquote)
            unlist(x)
        }
    }
    unquote(substitute(expr))
}

escapedNames(a + .(b) + c)
#> [1] "b"
```

As you can see, it works just fine for hard-coded expressions. However, I can't figure out how to pass calls stored in variables.

```r
f <- ~ a + .(b)
rhs <- rlang::f_rhs(f)
escapedNames(rhs)
#> NULL
```

This makes perfect sense, of course, since `escapedNames` treats whatever it is given as the call I want to analyze, so it doesn't know to expand `rhs` before looking for names.

So, how can I solve this?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the [`oshka`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/oshka/index.html) package. In this old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52330185/10782538) there's an example of it being used to evaluate nested calls. Maybe there's something useful there.

Answer (score 3):

Immediately after posting the bounty I figured a way to do it, but please show me a better way!

We can use `eval` and `rlang::expr` to force the expansion of the formula variable before evaluating `escapedNames`:

```r
escapedNames <- function (expr) 
{
    unquote <- function(e) {
        if (is.pairlist(e) || length(e) <= 1L) NULL
        else if (e[[1L]] == as.name("."))      deparse(e[[2L]])
        else                                   unlist(sapply(e, unquote))
    }
    unquote(substitute(expr))
}

formula <- ~ a + .(b) + c + .(d)
rhs <- rlang::f_rhs(formula)

eval(rlang::expr(escapedNames(!!rhs)))
#> [1] "b" "d"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>